# SFTP through proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, sftp

I have a large amount of data on scratch space at *computer b* that I want to get.

In my network I cannot directly connect to *computer b* (ssh exits with "No route to host"); I must first connect to *computer a*, and then connect to *computer b*.

I cannot move the data from the scratch space on *computer b* to *computer a* because of a disk quota that is imposed on me at *computer a*.

How can I move the data from *computer b* to *my computer* in this situation?

Comment: How can you connect to computer b?

Answer (score 2):

If `nc` suggested by Ignacio is not available on computerA, you can create a tunnel:

```
ssh -f -N -L 1234:computerB:22 computerA
```

(drop `-f` to keep it from going to the background). You should then be able to connect to port 1234 on `localhost` to access computerB, i.e.

```
scp -P 1234 user_on_computerB@localhost:/awesome/stuff/there /here
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProxyCommand` in your ssh config, along with nc on computer A:

```
Host computerB
    ProxyCommand ssh computerA nc computerB 22
```

Answer (score 0):

- one option is to mount b into a, from a:

  ```
  sshfs computer_b /mnt/PC_b
  ```

then copy directly to the mount

- another option if a and b machines are in the same LAN, to export via NFS data folder from b machine and mount it in a machine